# Error: TypeError: message.guild.channels.find is not a function

Tags: discord.js

I have a problem with finding a channel! Code:

```
    let chan = `ticket-${message.author.username}`;

    if (message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === chan)) {
            message.channel.send("You already have a channel!")
    }
```

Error:

```
TypeError: message.guild.channels.find is not a function
```

I hope someone can help me! :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 0):

Since discord.js v12 you need to access the `channels` collection using `cache` so your solution would be:

```js
let chan = `ticket-${message.author.username}`;

    if (message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === chan)) {
            message.channel.send("You already have a channel!")
    }
```

Comment: If an answer solves your question/issue, you need to accept it to let others know the question has been answered and to let others know what worked.

Comment: I still have a question about this, I am working on a kind of ticket system. Suppose someone has a ticket open called `ticket - $ {message.author.username}` how can I prevent that person from making another ticket? Because the way I try it doesn't work.

Comment: Please refrain from asking multiple questions in 1 question post. It doesn't help others who could be searching for answers